# Shift k array elements after a given array index

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Initial array: `2 23 34 27 89 14 26 30 60`

`k = 3`

starting from index i = 1 we have to shift k elements so that they occur after the element 26 (i.e. after givenIndex = 6) in the array.

Final array:   `2 89 14 26 23 34 27 30 60`

We are NOT allowed to use extra space.

My approach:

```
count = 0;   
while(count < k)  
{  
  count++;  
  temp = arr[i];  
  shift all elements from (i+1) to givenIndex to their immediate left position;  
  arr[givenIndex] = temp;  
}
```

First iteration:
`temp = 23`
shift all elements from [i+1](i.e. index=2) to givenIndex(i.e. index=6) to left one by one
array after shifting: `2 34 27 89 14 26 26 30 60`
arr[givenIndex] = temp
array after applying this operation: `2 34 27 89 14 26 23 30 60`

Similarly
array after second iteration: `2 27 89 14 26 23 34 30 60`
array after third iteration: `2 89 14 26 23 34 27 30 60`

worst case complexity O(n*k) where n is the no. of elemnts in the array.

Can we solve the problem in O(n)

Comment: Wait... what? How did the shifting take place? Can you please explain a bit more. It's not clear much. From my point of view, I see some numbers swapped.

Comment: Do we have to preserve the ordering or not?

Comment: @MatinKh I have edited thequestion. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: What would also help is your definition of "extra space" - I see you are using a temp variable, so is that all that is allowed, or is not even that allowed (worst case), or can we use so much we can create another array of the same size (best case)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here @Prateek. In your approach I see one loop, and no other conditions. I guarantee you that there is no worst-case here, as it's not dependent to any special case. It is o(n), or there must be something else we don't see here. We are speaking of time complexity, are we not?

Comment: We are allowed to use a temporary varaible. But we aren't allowed to use space proportional to the number of elements being swapped. i.e. in the example mentioned in my question we can't use an extra space of O(k) where k is the number of elements we have to shift.

Comment: @MatinKh the shifting would be done using a loop so there are two loops in my algorithm.

Comment: As there is 'k' rotation, it would be o(n * k). right? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *rotation* can be done in linear time using a `reverse()` helper function. Assuming that `reverse(x, y)` reverses `array[x]..array[y]` in place.

```
reverse(1, 3); // 27 34 23 .. .. ..
reverse(4, 6); // .. .. .. 26 14 89
reverse(1, 6); // 89 14 26 23 34 27
```

Writing a linear-time `reverse` is simple and might even be available in your favorite language library (for example, C++ includes `std::rotate` and `std::reverse`).

Comment: I don't think it improves the time-complexity.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can tell from your code(and the example), I think you are trying to put the block `[i,i+k-1]` after the block `[i+k,givenIndex]`

If that is the case, @Blastfurnace 's suggestion does lead to one solution in O(n) and no extra space:

simply do:

```
reverse(i,givenIndex)
reverse(i,givenIndex-k)
reverse(givenIndex-k+1,givenIndex)
```

and you have what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite amazing
See your requested answer here. If you are looking for a way to rotate your arraylist using JAVA, there is a complete solution for you [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29).
`public static void rotate(List list, int distance)`
Simply rotate your collection (ArrayList or LinkedList ...)
Its parameters are a `list` (in your case `arraylist`) and a `distance` (in your case `k`). Do you see the similarities? Simply use this.

Comment: That Java method uses the `3 reverse` algorithm for large lists. The description even mentions Jon Bentley's _Programming Pearls_ where I first learned the algorithm.

Comment: Sure it does. So? To find out the solution he has to learn the algorithm too. But if he is using java, he can simply take advantage of the rotation which is using that.